# Couldn't locate otool-classic while running ipatool

Tags: xcode, otool, ipatool

Running ipatool errors out.

```
xcrun ipatool ~/app.ipa --output=foo --info --json=foo/ipatool.info.json
```

It prints the following error

```json
 "alerts": [
    {   
      "level": "ERROR",
      "type": "exception",
      "code": 1094,
      "description": "ipatool failed with an exception: #<RuntimeError: Couldn't locate otool-classic in /Applications/Xcode13.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin ... /Applications/Xcode13.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:298:in `locate_tool'\n /Applications/Xcode13.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2083:in `<main>'",
      "info": {
      }   
    }   
  ]
```

Where should I get `otool-classic` from. My machine has the `otool` that comes with the xcode toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

I figure out a solution. You need to locate the tool in question and copy it in one of the directories scanned by xcrun.

Here an example:

```
xcrun --find otool-classic
```

Output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool-classic
```

Then copy it:

```
cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool-classic /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Finally, you can run your command:

```
xcrun ipatool --compile-bitcode -o recompiledBuil.ipa myBuild.ipa
```

Comment: This solution definitely solved my problem! thanks